# Can't save tags in django

Tags: django, django-taggit

i am using django-taggit to save tags. It save some tags but now its not working and idk why! still finding the solution. Please help me to find out what i am doing wrong. I am not getting any errors. But when i  save the form using form.save_m2m() nothing is saved in my database. I have also checked my admin pannel. Nothing is storing in my db. Is there is any way to check this. I am also attaching the template.

---

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from . models import UserCreatedNote
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from . forms import AddNoteForm
from taggit.models import Tag
# Create your views here.
@login_required
def notes(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AddNoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           
            form_data = form.save(commit=False)
            form_data.user = request.user
            key = form_data.note_title
            form_data.slug = unique_slug_generator(slugify(key))
            
            
            form_data.save()
            #to save tags
            form.save_m2m()
            

            
        notes = UserCreatedNote.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        form = AddNoteForm()
        context = {'notes': notes,'add_note_form':form}
        return render(request,'usernotes.html',context)
    
    notes = UserCreatedNote.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    form = AddNoteForm()
    context = {'notes': notes,'add_note_form':form}
    return render(request,'usernotes.html',context)
@login_required
def edit(request,slug):
    note = get_object_or_404(UserCreatedNote, slug=slug)
    tagsList = []
    for tag in note.note_tags.all():
        tagsList.append(tag.name)
    print(tagsList)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddNoteForm(request.POST, instance=note)
      
        if form.is_valid():
            
            
            form_data = form.save(commit=False)
            form_data.user = request.user
            key = form_data.note_title
            form_data.slug = unique_slug_generator(slugify(key))
           
          
            form_data.save()
            #to save tags
            form.save_m2m()
      
        form = AddNoteForm(instance=note)
        context={'note':note,'u_form':form}
    
        return render(request,'edit_note.html',context)
    
    
    
    form = AddNoteForm(instance=note)
    context={'note':note,'u_form':form}
    
    return render(request,'edit_note.html',context)
```

---

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
# Create your models here.
class UserCreatedNote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(),on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note_title = models.CharField(default='',max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    note_tags = TaggableManager()
    note_data = RichTextField(default='',max_length=5000,blank=True,null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,max_length=100)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        
        ordering = ['-creation_time',]
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

---

**template**

```
 <form action="" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          {{ add_note_form.media }}
          {% for field in add_note_form %}
          <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12">
              {{ field | as_crispy_field }}
          </div>
         
          {% endfor %}
          <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <label for="tags">Note Tags</label>
           <input type="text" id="tags" data-role="tagsinput" class="form-control" name="note_tags">
           </div>
        </div>
        
        
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      </form>
```